# Нахождение затраченого времени по времени начала и конца, неправильные данные на выводе

Tags: дата, datetime, java, время

Задача заключается в том, чтобы при известном дне, часе, минуте и секунде вычислить затраченое время и вывести ответ в формате (д ч м с). Я попытался вычислить время в миллисекундах и присвоить значение переменной типа лонг потом поставив это значение в качестве аргумента конструктора класса Date библиотеки java.util.Date вывести необходимое значение. Но, к сожалению, выходные данные очень далеки от ожидаемых.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ModuloAndTimeDifference {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File text = new File("C:\\Users\\Andrew\\IdeaProjects\\ModuloAndTimeDifference\\src\\ModuloAndTimeDifference.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(text);
        scanner.nextLine();
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
            long result = (((-1000) * ((scanner.nextLong() * 24 * 60 * 60) + (scanner.nextLong() * 60 * 60) + (scanner.nextLong() * 60) + (scanner.nextLong()))) + (1000 * ((scanner.nextLong() * 24 * 60 * 60) + (scanner.nextLong() * 60 * 60) + (scanner.nextLong() * 60) + scanner.nextLong())));
            DateFormat Timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("d h m s");
            System.out.print("(" + Timestamp.format(new Date(result))+ ") ");

        }
    }
}
```

Скажите, что пошло не так. Конечно, можно было бы вручную задать подсчет и банальные инты на вывод кинуть, но для меня приоритетная цель научиться "кодить". Поэтому я стараюсь творчески подходить к выполнению заданий. ) Заранее спасибо.

Comment: например данные на входе

3
1 0 0 0 2 3 4 5
5 3 23 22 24 4 20 45
8 4 6 47 9 11 51 13

на выходе такая ересь

(2 5 4 5) (20 2 57 23) (2 9 44 26)

Comment: Ок. Спасибо посмотрю. Я изначально хотел реализовать, как прибавить время конца и начала к 1 января 1970 и посчитать разницу в миллисекундах, но не совсем понял реализацию метода. В общем, загвоздка в конструкторе new Date(), то в чем я был уверен на 100%.

Comment: А тем более если сложный, так вообще обязательно надо разобраться)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конструктор `new Date(long date)` принимает параметром не абстрактные миллисекунды, а количество миллисекунд, прошедших с `1 января 1970 г. 00:00:00 GMT`.

Так для интервала в 1 секунду в вашем файле, ваша формула выдаст 1000 миллисекунд. Это будет соответствовать дате `1 января 1970 г 00:00:01 GMT`. `SimpleDateFormat` переведет это в вашу тайм-зону, что для московского времени даст на выходе что-то вроде: `31 21 50 1`.

P.S. Время, на мой взгляд, это один самых сложных типов данных. И в этой области лучше не городить велосипеды, а пользоваться существующими решениями. Посмотрите библиотеку [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) и новый [Java 8 Time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html).